# StringList in VBA

Tags: vba

A function I'm using in VBA returns a variable `ErrorTags` which has to be defined as type `StringList`.  In Debug watch if I watch `ErrorTags` I can see string variables returned as Item 1, Item 2 etc.  However I can't find any way in the code to access these variables.  Eg I've tried

```
Test = ErrorTags.Item 1
```

and

```
Test = ErrorTags.Item_1
```

without any success

What is the correct format?

Comment: If it's a collection use "ErrorTags. Item(1)" or " ErrorTags(1)"

Comment: `StringList` is not a native VBA type.  Where and how is it defined in your code?

Comment: 'Debug Watch' and `StringList` all sounds very Visual Studio. Is it possible your mean `VB.Net` rather than `VBA`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ErrorTags` is indeed a collection, you have to think of it like this:

`ErrorTags` is an object that holds all the values associated with it (the *Items* you see in the watch list). That object has a default property, `Item`. That property can return all the values stored in the object, but only one at a time. Which will be returned depends on the parameter you pass to the property:

```
ErrorTags.Items(1)
```

This will return the first item stored in the collection. The parameter serves as an index by which you can address all items in the collection. Some collections in VBA also accept strings as an index, but that depends on the type of collection. In Excel, for example, the `Sheets` property of a workbook returns a collection (containing all the worksheets in an Excel file). That collection does not only take numbers as an index but also works with the sheet name as an index.

As said above, the `Item` property of a collection is the *default* property. In VBA, an object can have a default property, which means, it can be omitted. To access the first item from your collection can therefore also be written like this:

```
ErrorTags(1)
```

Now, you probably want sometimes to access not just one item but all of them in a loop. You could do this with a `For` loop using the counter as an index for the collection.
But there is a better way:

```
Dim et As Variant

For Each et In ErrorTags
    ' now you have one item stored in et, do with it as you like
Next et
```

Using a `For Each` loop you can iterate over all items of a collection (it also works for arrays). For each pass the current item will be written to the variable `et`. Use that variable instead of `ErrorTags.Items()` as long as you are in the loop. Assuming the items in the `ErrorTags` collection are simple strings you could output all of them to the immediate window if you put `Debug.Print et` in the body of the loop.

If the items in your collection are objects themselves, then you should change the declaration of the variable `et` to that object type:

```
Dim et As ErrorTag ' assuming that is the object type
```

More information about the `For Each` loop can be obtained from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx).